# Getting result of current city from LocationListener in separate class

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

Hi i have implemented a Location listener to retrieve the current city name. The only problem that i am having is that i am not too sure what is the best way to return the result to the calling class (MainActivity.java).

This is are some excerpt of my code:

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)   
                  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        flag = displayGpsStatus(); 
        if (flag) {
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener(getApplicationContext());
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager  
                       .GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,locationListener);
        }else{
            Log.i("DEBUG", "UNABLE TO RETRIEVE LOCATION");
        }

        String lang = "en";

        findViewById();
    }
```

and this is my **LocationListener** class (on separated java file)

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private String mLocality;
    private String mCountry;

    public MyLocationListener(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //You had this as int. It is advised to have Lat/Loing as double.
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        String countryName = null;
        String subAdmin  = null;
        String adminArea  = null;
        String locality  = null;
        String sublocality  = null;

        String longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
        Log.i("DEBUG", longitude);
        Log.i("DEBUG", latitude);

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if(address.size() > 0){
                adminArea = address.get(0).getAdminArea().toString();
                countryName = address.get(0).getCountryName().toString();
                subAdmin = address.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                locality = address.get(0).getLocality();
                sublocality = address.get(0).getSubLocality();
            }
            Log.i("DEBUG", adminArea);
            Log.i("DEBUG", countryName);
            mLocality = adminArea;
            mCountry = countryName;
        } catch (IOException e) {}
          catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Disabled provider " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "Enabled new provider " + provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

what i am trying to achieve is to have the city name displayed when the app started and when ever the location is changed.

Should i call onLocationChange() or else?
Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thx for the help.

Comment: You can let the `Activity` implement the `LocationListener` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Extract everything in the onLocationChanged to a method (or a class and put that method in it). Call that method on startup and from the onLocationChanged